# Converting inheritance to composition in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop, design-patterns, inheritance

I have a model in a legacy system that looks something like this:

```
 class Prize < ActiveRecord::Base

   def win
     # do a bunch of things
   end
 end
```

We started off with one prize, but like anything else the type of prizes we are dealing with is starting to expand.  So now def win is doing a whole bunch of case/switching to decide prize type.

For that reason I decided to do this:

```
class DailyPrize < Prize
   def win
     #do only daily prize stuff, no type checking.
   end
end
```

This code came under review before we sent it off to QA and now I am asked to do this using composition (mixin) and not subclassing.  I cannot think of a clean way to do this.

The legacy code base is doing the following in a bunch of places and I did not want to go changing stuff all over the place:

prize = Prize.new
prize.win

So, my question how to make this happen using composition?

Comment: While I believe that composition is often the better choice, what is the argument for using it here - are there more inheritance levels that you didn't show? Also, are you using STI? Doing that in a sane way more or less requires the common subclass. I'm kind of confused by the "I am asked to do it in that way part" - was the person doing the review not convincing you (and showing you how it could be done better)?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I was not given a reason on why I should do it using composition, but just to make it happen.  I added the type column last night and will be using STI. The levels of inheritance are simply two: Prize and it's children.

Answer (score 4):

Here is what I understand by replacing your code by composition over inheritance.

```
class Prize < ActiveRecord::Base

  def prize
    @prize ||= PrizeFactory.build(self)
  end

  def win
    prize.win
  end
end

class PrizeFactory
  def self.build(prize)
    if prize.daily?
      DailyPrize.new(prize)
    # other condition to build specific prize
    end
  end
end


class DailyPrize
  def initialize(prize)
    @prize = prize
  end

  def win
    #do only daily prize stuff
    #access @prize to get @prize attribute
    #if you use it, you have coupling (see below)
  end
end
```

The thing is, this may not be better than your implementation, it really depend of what your are achieving in term of domain logic.

With composition, one goal is to reduce the coupling between object, if you are calling a lot of `@prize` object methods in the `DailyPrice` `win` method , you have a tight coupling between this two classes and you may lost the benefits of composition.

Answer (score 0):

One way I can think of is having specific prizes as Modules, e.g.

```
module DailyPrize
  def specific_method_1
  end

  def specific_method_2
  end
end
```

... and then having the Prize class as :

```
class Prize
  def win
    # do something in common
    specific_method_1
    # do something in common
    specific_method_2
    # ...
  end
end
```

And then you can mixin a module as you choose, for example when instantiating the class

```
def initialize (prize_type)
  # mixin the appropriate module
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the response Matko.

Comment: FYI modules are also inheritance.